# SQL Server 2000 Transfer Logins and Associated Server Roles and Access to Specific Databases

Tags: t-sql, authentication, sql-server-2000, roles

I work for a relatively small company less than 50 people and I'm probably the closest thing we have to a DBA...I'm actually a programmer but that's beside the point.  We have a `SQL Server 2000` with about **100 different databases**.  Almost all of those have an associated SQL Login and that Login is tied to a `DB_OWNER` database role for a particular database.  We also have some logins that are set to the `DB_DATAREADER` database role.

We have purchased a brand new machine (current one 12 years old and worried about a hardware failure that may take our business down for an unacceptable amount of time).  We are NOT upgrading the SQL Server Version.  We are going to stick with 2000.

My question is what is the easiest way to do this.  My thoughts are to detach all of the databases, copy them over to the new machine, and then reattach each of the databases.  I'm going to keep the machine name and IP's the same and just remove old server when done so no connection strings anywhere have to be modified.  That doesn't seem so bad and can easily get that done on a weekend.  My problem with this method is that after I do that I need to delete User from the database, then recreate the `login` with username/password, and then assign the appropriate role for each user.  I've only been here 5 years and I don't have all of possible usernames/passwords that each particular database and program is using.  I don't want to break any existing programs or have to go to every single machine and update this...or possibly even have to find old source code and recompile...yes some of our legacy stuff has the username/password hardcoded in the source :(.

So I guess the main question is their a `script` that I can run on the existing server that will generate a script to run on the new machine to setup the existing `logins`, `users`, `roles` with same username/password as before?

If there is an easier way of transfering a sql server instance from one machine to another; I'm all ears.

FYI we have tried creating a VHD from the existing server to use in a virtual machine but have exausted that route.  We never were able to get the machine to boot into windows.  Think that was driver issues.

Comment: Did you already see this instruction page: [transfer and logins passwords between sql server instances](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133)? Seems to have info that would help you acheive exactly what you want.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on  dba.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are running the 64-bit version of SQL server on the destination machine, the link supplied in the first comment should allow you to transfer logins successfully.

The section titled "A complete resolution to transfer logins and passwords between different versions of SQL Server" in [that link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133) provides you with a step-by-step procedure to accomplish your goal.

Although doing this is certainly very risky, you could always create an image of the existing server's drive using some tool like [Norton Ghost](http://us.norton.com/ghost/) and restore that image on the new hardware.

I have done this when migrating to a solid state drive from a traditional drive and it worked just fine although took a long time (several hours).  Of course this approach won't work if you are changing the OS and may not work correctly due to hardware and driver differences.

It would certainly be much more work, but these kinds of upgrades give you a chance to correct some of the problems that are making it difficult for you to migrate the db server to a new installation (e.g.: hard-coded credentials, etc.). If you have the ability, time and desire to correct these issues, it may be worthwhile to do so.

Comment: Moving an OS on a completely different hardware is hazardous. Maybe for Linux, but definitely not for Windows.

Comment: Yes, I think this would only work if OP was changing disks, and only in limited circumstances at that.

Answer (score 3):

I thought you might be able to shut the server down and then copy all database related files to the new server and restart the new sqlserver there having it use these copied files. Cannot find much more beside this though http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost959329.aspx

This link gives you the support opinion of what to do http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314546

Considering the VHD route, did you also try a competing product? You might give VMWare a try, I have heard very good things about it and it might succeed where others failed. http://www.vmware.com/nl/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html

Comment: First link seems geared towards 2005.  That being said I'm a little leary of copying the master, moodel, msdb, and tempdb.  I guess to be honest with you I'm not even sure where login info would be probably the master database.

Comment: I also really didn't want to go the route of copying the c:\programfiles\microsoft sql server\ directory either.  I'm sure that there would be associated registry entries that I would need to get just right as well.  I don't know for fact but I'm guessing the OS version between the two might be different if we rebuild from scratch.

Comment: As for the VMWare we have not tried it.  We generally try and stick with MS when we can.  It might be worth a shot if they offer a trial.  We got several VM around the office that are done through microsofts Hyper-V servers so adding VMWare into the mix is just one extra thing one of us would need to learn and maintain...but it still might be a better option than building up from scratch.  I'll ask to see if that is an option for us.

Comment: I'll also take a look at your second miscroft link in more detail.  It's got quite a few sublinks so it may take a while to digest

Answer (score 2):

Been a long, long time since I hacked SQL 2000... but it was hackable, in ways that don't apply to 2005 and up.  The following are ideas and suggestions based on old memories of "what happens if we do *this*..."; I can't give you specific commands or examples, because I don't have access to any SQL 2000 instances just now.

- Create a backup of the "New" master database.
- Two instances of SQL 2000 on two different boxes. Call them "old" and "new".
- Shut down old
- Copy the master database files (master.mdf, master.log, or whatever they're named) to the new server
- Make sure you have a backup of the "New" master database.
- Attach them to the new instance as a user database. Rename the files, maybe "OldMaster".
- Locate the appropriate system databases in both Master databases. SysLogins? SysLoginX? Books Online will help here (these system tables have been completely revised since 2000).
- INSERT... SELECT... from one database to the other. I'm fairly certain I did this once upon a time. (Right before we dropped the SA account, just to see if we could.) (Oh, don't drop the SA account.)
- I think there's some sp_options switch you have to flip, to allow manual updates of the system databases.
- You did make that backup of the "New" master database, didn't you? (Actually, shutting down the instance, copying the master database files, and starting them up again worked ok as well -- just shut down, copy the copies back over your messed up files, and start up again, and you're where you were -- so long as you haven't messed with any other databases.)

`sp_change_users_login` (using "report" then "autofix") should prove invaluable here -- it can be used to synch logins (definitions in the master database) with users (definitions stored in the datbases). Once again, not applicable where I am now, but time was I had to use this procedure every time we moved a databases from one box to another.  Huh.  There was *some* way to script out a login with encrypted password, and run that "create login" on another box, but I cannot recall what it was. Look over the documentation for sp_CreateLogin, or whatever was used to create a SQL login on 2000.

Most everything I ever figured out came from reading **Books Online**, and then messing around. I don't know if you have the time, but if you have the requirement, it can eventually be made to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way should be after you have installed the new server
(i would say reconsider upgrading to sql2008 or higher for a great number of reasons).

And then use the copy database wizard. Follow the steps described at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

greetings,
jaco